# What organizations handle the TLD registries and what are the links to their whois search pages

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, whois

**Cautionary Tale: Registrars get rich by screwing you out of money**

My first foray into web design included a site with a handful of issues. The original designer/developer created it as a one-off and he didn't bother to mention to the owner that the name would expire in 2 years.

When I stepped in to take over, the name had expired and the registrar (InterNIC) was charging $250 USD to get it back. The site at the time was a general static business site that didn't have a big enough following to warrant the price of the .com name so we opted to move to .net. All in all, it took 5 years before the registrar finally released the name so we could finally recover it.

**tl;dr: Don't trust registrars.**

Considering the emergence of [Domain Front Running](http://www.domainwarning.com/):

> This is where a domain registrar or an intermediary (like a domain lookup site) mines the searches for possibly attractive domains and then either sells the data to a third-party, or goes ahead and registers the name themselves ahead of you. In one case a registrar took advantage of what's known as the "grace period" and registered every single domain users looked up through them and held on to them for 5 days before releasing them back into the pool at no cost to themselves.

I have good reason to distrust 3rd party registrars. To compensate, I only use the whois of the TLD owner to do domain searches.

I have been using verisign to look-up .com/.net domains for years now but what I'd like to know is:

**Who owns the following TLDs and where can I find their Whois search:**

- .com - Verisign Inc. - [whois](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/whois/index.xhtml)
- .net - Verisign Inc. - [whois](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/whois/index.xhtml)
- .org - PIR - [whois](http://www.pir.org/get/whois)
- .edu - Educause - [whois](http://whois.educause.edu)
- .biz - Neustar - [whois](http://www.whois.biz/)
- .pro - Registry.Pro - [whois](http://www.registrypro.pro/)

Comment: What happened to community wiki? I don't need the rep. I'd rather have good reference that others can edit.

Comment: The wiki toggle was removed for a few reasons you can find covered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action). You can request a question be converted by flagging for mod action.

Comment: @Su' Good to know. It turns out that one answer is enough to cover the question so a wiki is unnecessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of each authoritative WHOIS server is available in the IANA database.
For example

- [.edu](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/edu.html)
- [.mil](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/mil.html)

and so on.

Comment: Nice. That's exactly what I was looking for.